# cross product of E and H

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, cross-product

Can anyone explain how they came up with the product of E and H ? I don't understand why the exponent of E cross H are multiplied by 2.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: They used the distributive property to multiply the first term by the difference of the other two. In doing so, the exponents added together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, the $a_y$ component of the product is found by
$$
[5e^{-j3x}e^{j2y}][-2.53e^{-j3x}e^{j2y}](\mathbf a_z \times \mathbf a_x) = \\
-12.65 e^{-j3x - j3x}e^{j2y + j2y} \mathbf a_y = \\
-12.65 e^{-j6x}e^{j4y}
$$
And this simply follows from the rule $b^cb^d = b^{c+d}$.  I hope this clarification is sufficient.

Comment: shouldn't the -j3x-j3x=-j6x?

Comment: and it should be -12.65 . I think you made an error, but thanks, it is very clear.

Comment: Fixed the typos